# CakePHP paginate error with JsHelper

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

After adding this:

```
public function index() 
{
    $this->paginate['User']['conditions'] = array('User.role' => 'admin');
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```

I receive this:

> Strict (2048): Declaration of JsHelper::value() should be compatible
>   with Helper::value($options = Array, $field = NULL, $key = 'value')
>   [CORE/Cake/View/Helper/JsHelper.php, line 34]

what is that mean? and what does it do? Btw I never do anything with the JsHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it: 
changed the PHP version from `5.4.10` to `5.2.17`